# The names 'array1' and 'getnum' do not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string getnums = Console.ReadLine();
        int getnum=Convert.ToInt32(getnums);
        int[] array1=new int[getnum];
        
        GenerateNum(getnum);
        RevArray();
        PrintArray();
    }
    static int[] GenerateNum(int g){
        
        for(int index=0; index<g; index++){
            array1[index]=index;
        }
        return array1;
    }
    static int[] RevArray(){
        for(int index=0; index<=getnum/2; index++){
            int a=array1[index];
            array1[index]=array1[getnum];
            array1[getnum]=a;
        }
        return array1;
    }
    static void PrintArray(){
        Console.WriteLine(array1);
    }
}
```

Hi. I'm trying to write a program with three methods and each of them does one action. `GenerateNum()` takes `getnum` as a parameter and creates an array with numbers up to getnum. `RevArray()` reverses the array and `PrintArray()` prints it out. However I get error messages. All of them are name `'array1'` and name `'getnum'` does not exist in the current context. I have defined them in the `Main` method, then why doesn't it work? Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those variables are local to the `Main` function so you can't access them. You need to declare them in a wider scope (Like defining them as fields of `Program` class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have defined them in the Main method

Variables defined in some method `A` are only available to that method. If you want to use them in other methods, you need to either

- declare them in a wider *scope* (for example, by making them static fields of your class) or by
- passing them as parameters.

The latter is usually preferable (see, e.g. [Are global variables bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad)).

---

For example, `GenerateNum` could be defined as

```
 static int[] GenerateNum(int g, int[] array1) { ... }
```

and called as

```
GenerateNum(getnum, array1);
```

There are lots of other things that could be improved in your code (for example, you do not need to return arrays if you modify them in-place, and GenerateNum could allocate the array itself instead of requiring an array with the correct size to be passed), so you might want to submit your code to https://codereview.stackexchange.com after you got it running.